# Confusion in sign convention of magnification?

Tags: optics, conventions, geometric-optics

> A concave mirror forms a real image three times larger than the object on a screen. Object and screen are moved until the image becomes twice the size of object. If the shift of object is 6 cm. Find the focal length and initial position of object?
>   **Sign convention used :- New cartesian sign conventions**

**My attempt :-**

First way

As per question 
$$m_i=3$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{-f}{-f+u}=3$$
$$\Longrightarrow 2f=3u.     \tag1$$
For second case, in a similar way we get
$$ \frac{-f}{-f+(u+6)}=3$$
$$ \Longrightarrow f=2u+12.  \tag2$$
Solving equation 1 and 2 we get
$$f=-36 , u=-24$$

2nd way 
Since the image is inverted the magnification must be negative.
So $$m_i =-3$$
$$\Longrightarrow \frac{f}{f-u}=-3$$
For the second case 
$$\frac{f}{f-(u+6)}=-2$$
Solving we get
$$f=-36, u=-48$$

**My question:** Why do I get two different answer, if use a different sign convention in the formula of magnification? Why does this happen and which is right procedure to follow?

Comment: You should state which sign convention you are using.  I think that the reason you get two answers is that one method of solution the double size image is real and in the other method the double size image is virtual.

Comment: More precisely you should write whether with positive magnification the image is oriented in the same way as the object in physical space.